# Concatenating arrays in bigquery with empty arrays

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

Then I try to aggregate the label1, label2, label3 into one array for each type of label and then, finally I want to put all the non null labels into one combined array. So my query looks like this

```
#standardSQL
WITH
table AS (
SELECT 'abc' id, 1 label1, 12 label2, 122 label3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', 1, 12, 129 UNION ALL
SELECT 'xyz', 2, 23, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 'xyz', 2, 24, NULL
),

each_label_agg AS (
 SELECT
 id,
 ARRAY_AGG(label1 IGNORE NULLS) AS label1_agg,
 ARRAY_AGG(label2 IGNORE NULLS) AS label2_agg,
 ARRAY_AGG(label3 IGNORE NULLS) AS label3_agg
FROM
table
GROUP BY
 id)
SELECT
 each_label_agg.*,
 ARRAY_CONCAT(each_label_agg.label1_agg, each_label_agg.label2_agg, 
 each_label_agg.label3_agg) AS combined_labels
FROM
 each_label_agg
```

And the output looks like this:

[image]

But in the output I was expecting the `combined_labels` to be `[2,2,23,24]` for id `xyz`.

The `ignore nulls` parameter doesn't work in `array_concat`. I am guessing somehow the `combined_labels` become malformed because of an empty array at `label3`. How can I get the expected `combined_labels` for `xyz` to be `[2,2,23,24]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
WITH table AS (
  SELECT 'abc' id, 1 label1, 12 label2, 122 label3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', 1, 12, 129 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', 2, 23, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', 2, 24, NULL
), each_label_agg AS (
 SELECT
   id,
   ARRAY_AGG(label1 IGNORE NULLS) AS label1_agg,
   ARRAY_AGG(label2 IGNORE NULLS) AS label2_agg,
   ARRAY_AGG(label3 IGNORE NULLS) AS label3_agg
  FROM table
  GROUP BY id
)
SELECT
  each_label_agg.*,
  ARRAY_CONCAT(
   IFNULL(each_label_agg.label1_agg, []), 
   IFNULL(each_label_agg.label2_agg, []),
   IFNULL(each_label_agg.label3_agg, [])
  ) AS combined_labels
FROM each_label_agg
```

Comment: Works perfectly as I wanted!! Thanks again. But the way it had to be handled seemed to me a bit counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this issue is because BigQuery has [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#array-type) respect to `NULL` values and the array generation will return `NULL` if any argument is `NULL` as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#generate_array). Therefore, it is convenient to substitute them for empty arrays (since `NULL`s and empty arrays are two distinct values in BigQuery)